# comparing two different array types in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two different array types. One of them string array another object array;

```
stringArray = ["P1", "P2", "P3"];
objectArray = [{ P: "P1", PO: 5}, { P: "P3", PO: 10}];
```

I want to put object array to a table. String array elements must be table headers.

If object array has `P == "P1"` put 5 to cell. Else put empty cell to row.

I tried this but this put multiple empty cells.

This is my code "tKeys" = stringArray, "Ciktilar" = objectArray

```
var baslikEklendiMi = false;
var satirEkle = function(CalismaTipi, Ciktilar, tKeys)
{
    var satir = '<td>' + CalismaTipi + '</td>';
    $.each(tKeys, function (i, val) {
        if (baslikEklendiMi == false) {
            $("#tblBaslik").append("<th>" + val+ "</th>");
        }

        $.each(Ciktilar, function (j, obj) {
            if (val == obj.P) {
                satir += '<td><b>' + obj.PO+ '</b></td>';
            }
            else {
                satir += '<td></td>';
            }
        });
    });

    baslikEklendiMi = true;
    $("#tblListe").append('<tr>' + satir + '</tr>');
}
```

Comment: Not clear what expected results are. What does *" put empty cell to row"* mean? Provide a [mcve] demo in jsfiddle.net or plunker with sample data and expected end result sample

Comment: @charlietfl your right. I will follow directives next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get something like:

```
|--|--|--|--|
|ct|P1|P2|P3|
|--|--|--|--|
|??|5 |  |10|
|--|--|--|--|
```

There are five changes that need to be made to your code:

1) Line 7 (below): Instantiate `emptyCell`, assign `false`;

2) Line 9: Add `$("#tblBaslik").append("<th>ct</th>")` to account for `CalismaTipi` column,

3) Line 25-27: Move `satir += '<td></td>'` to outside the `Ciktilar` loop.

4) Line 22: Assign `true` to `emptyCell`.

5) Line 18-19: Reset `emptyCell` and exit the `Ciktilar` loop.

```
var stringArray  = ["P1", "P2", "P3"];
var objectArray  = [{ P: "P1", PO: 5}, { P: "P3", PO: 10}];

var baslikEklendiMi = false;
var satirEkle = function(CalismaTipi, Ciktilar, tKeys)
{
    var emptyCell = false;                                // Line 7
    var satir = '<td>' + CalismaTipi + '</td>';
    $("#tblBaslik").append("<th>ct</th>");                // Line 9
    $.each(tKeys, function (i, val) {
        if (baslikEklendiMi === false) {
            $("#tblBaslik").append("<th>" + val+ "</th>");
        }

        $.each(Ciktilar, function (j, obj) {
            if (val == obj.P) {
                satir += '<td><b>' + obj.PO+ '</b></td>';
                emptyCell = false;                         // Line 18
                return false;
            }
            else {
              emptyCell = true;                            // Line 22
            }
        });
        if (emptyCell) {                                   // Line 24
            satir += '<td></td>';
        }
    });

    baslikEklendiMi = true;
    $("#tblListe").append('<tr>' + satir + '</tr>');
};
satirEkle('??', objectArray, stringArray);
```

The reason you need to move `satir += '<td></td>';` outside the `Ciktilar` loop is because the `stringArray` list does not correspond directly to the `objectArray` list. You want to check ALL the `stringArray` elements to find a match, and if no match after ALL the `stringArray` elements are checked THEN write an empty cell. So, rather than write to `satir` in the loop, set an `emptyCell` flag, and check that flag after the loop.

[JSBin example.](http://jsbin.com/nilabuxexa/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code like this:

```
var satirEkle = function(CalismaTipi, Ciktilar, tKeys) {
    var satir = '<td>' + CalismaTipi + '</td>';
    $.each(tKeys, function (i, val) {
        if (baslikEklendiMi == false) {
            $("#tblBaslik").append("<th>" + val+ "</th>");
        }
        var emptyCell = false;
        $.each(Ciktilar, function (j, obj) {
            if (val == obj.P) {
                satir += '<td><b>' + obj.PO+ '</b></td>';
            }
            else {
                emptyCell = true;
            }
        });

        if (emptyCell) {
            satir += '<td>-</td>';
        } 
    });

    baslikEklendiMi = true;
    $("#tblListe").append('<tr>' + satir + '</tr>');
}
```

You should add a char inside the empty cell to have a more friendly layout.

A good choose is the empty html space `&nbsp;`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to do with a tool that i use very often to generate table HTML from an array of object or objects. So the below code will generate a table for you. The generic `tableMaker` function takes an array of an object or an array of multiple objects provided in the first argument. All objects should have same keys (properties) since these keys are used to create the table header (if the second argument is set to true) and the values are used to create each row. It will return an HTML table text. You can see the tableMaker function working with a smaller size data at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643455/how-to-insert-table-rows-and-columns-with-2d-array/37643823#37643823). You can also practice it with some sample and simple data you may produce.

```js
var tableMaker = (o,h) => {var keys = o.length && Object.keys(o[0]),
                           rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                                           : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
                           rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
                           return rows.length ? "<table>" + rows + "</table>" : "";
                          },
   stringArray = ["P1", "P2", "P3"],
   objectArray = [{ P: "P1", PO: 5}, { P: "P3", PO: 10}],
   tableObject = stringArray.reduce((p,c) => {var fo = objectArray.find(f => f.P == c);
                                               p[c] = fo ? fo.PO : "";
                                               return p;} ,{}),
     tableHTML = tableMaker([tableObject],true);
document.write(tableHTML);
console.log(tableHTML);
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. this is works too but @bloodyKnuckles's solution easier for me.