# Populating a table from an Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a form and an array, I want to populate the data from the form to the array and then populate the data from the array to a table in order to see the data in the browser. I dont know why I can’t make this possible. Could you please help me to do it?

```js
var monTab = [];

document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function() {
  var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
  var nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
  var prenom = document.getElementById("prenom").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;

  monTab[id] = new Personne(id, nom, prenom, age);
  console.log(monTab);

  document.getElementById("id").value = calcId();

  clearinputs();
}

function calcId() {
  var id;
  id = monTab.length + 1;
  return id;
}

function clearinputs() {
  nom.value = "";
  prenom.value = "";
  age.value = "";
}

function Personne(id, nom, prenom, age) {
  this.nomFamille = nom;
  this.prenom = prenom;
  this.age = age;
  this.id = id;
}

function tablegenerator() {
  var contenu;
  for (var i = 0; i < monTab.length; i++) {
    contenu += monTab[i] + "<br>";
    var e = document.createElement('tr');
    var formligne = '<tr><td>' + monTab[i].id + '</td><td>' + monTab[i].nomFamille + '</td><td>' + monTab[i].prenom + '</td><td>' + monTab[i].age + '</td></tr>';
    e.innerHTML = formligne;

    document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[0].appendChild(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="controls">
    <button>Editer</button>
    <button>Eliminer</button>
  </div>

  <div id="formContainer">
    <form name="formDonnees">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Vos Coordonnées</legend>

        <label for="nom">Votre Nom</label>
        <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" />
        <br />

        <label for="prenom">Votre Prenom</label>
        <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom" />
        <br />

        <label for="age">Votre Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
        <br />

        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="0" />

        <input type="button" name="buttonAjout" id="button1" value="Save" />
        <br />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="all" class="datagrid">
    <table class="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Id</td>
          <td>Nom</td>
          <td>Prenom</td>
          <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: What error you are getting in console..?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `tr` element as a first child of the table which has `tbody` and `thead` tags. You need to add `tr` element to `tbody` element of table for showing content in table. Additionally inner HTML of this `tr` element you are creating has another tr element. You need to have only `td` elements there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `id` as `0` based index then don't add `1` in `calcId()`. I changed your `Eliminer` button with `generate table` clicking it will populate all your form data in table.

```js
var monTab = [];

document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function() {
  var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
  var nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
  var prenom = document.getElementById("prenom").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;

  monTab[id] = new Personne(id, nom, prenom, age);
  //console.log(monTab);

  document.getElementById("id").value = calcId();

  clearinputs();
}

function calcId() {
  var id;
  id = monTab.length;
  return id;
}

function clearinputs() {
  nom.value = "";
  prenom.value = "";
  age.value = "";
}

function Personne(id, nom, prenom, age) {
  this.nomFamille = nom;
  this.prenom = prenom;
  this.age = age;
  this.id = id;
}

function tablegenerator() {
  var contenu;
  for (var i = 0; i < monTab.length; i++) {
    contenu += monTab[i] + "<br>";
    var e = document.createElement('tr');
    var formligne = '<tr><td>' + monTab[i].id + '</td><td>' + monTab[i].nomFamille + '</td><td>' + monTab[i].prenom + '</td><td>' + monTab[i].age + '</td></tr>';
    e.innerHTML = formligne;

    document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[0].appendChild(e);
  }
}

document.getElementById("generate").onclick = function(){
  tablegenerator();
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="controls">
    <button>Editer</button>
    <button id="generate">Generate Table</button>
  </div>

  <div id="formContainer">
    <form name="formDonnees">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Vos Coordonnées</legend>

        <label for="nom">Votre Nom</label>
        <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" />
        <br />

        <label for="prenom">Votre Prenom</label>
        <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom" />
        <br />

        <label for="age">Votre Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
        <br />

        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="0" />

        <input type="button" name="buttonAjout" id="button1" value="Save" />
        <br />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="all" class="datagrid">
    <table class="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Id</td>
          <td>Nom</td>
          <td>Prenom</td>
          <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified your code for some efficiency. Also adopted my [`tableMaker`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37777880/4543207) function for this application. It takes an array of values as the first argument and generate a table row from them. The second argument is to designate whether the cells will be "td" or "th" elements.

OK it's best to do minimal DOM access so we do it only once. Not even each form submit. We keep a reference to the `<fieldset>` element within the `Personne` constructor's prototype.

I use a lot of arrow function those probably won't run at IE or Safari so you  might need to replace them with their conventional counterparts.

OK let's see how it works. You can play with it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/BgteUan3c1xOpglg5yRW?p=preview).

```js
function Personne() {
  this.id         = this.fieldSet.children[10].value;
  this.nomFamille = this.fieldSet.children[2].value;
  this.prenom     = this.fieldSet.children[5].value;
  this.age        = this.fieldSet.children[8].value;
}

Personne.prototype.fieldSet = document.getElementById("fieldSet");

var rowMaker = (a, t) => a.reduce((p, c, i, a) => p + (i === a.length - 1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>" : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"), "<tr>");

document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function() {
  var monTab = [],
    personne = new Personne();

  monTab[personne.id] = personne;
  personne.fieldSet.children[10].value = monTab.length;
  personne.fieldSet.children[2].value = "";
  personne.fieldSet.children[5].value = "";
  personne.fieldSet.children[8].value = "";
  monTab = Object.keys(personne).map(k => personne[k]);
  document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[0].innerHTML += rowMaker(monTab, "td");
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="controls">
    <button>Editer</button>
    <button>Eliminer</button>
  </div>

  <div id="formContainer">
    <form name="formDonnees">
      <fieldset id="fieldSet">
        <legend>Vos Coordonnées</legend>

        <label for="nom">Votre Nom</label>
        <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" />
        <br />

        <label for="prenom">Votre Prenom</label>
        <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom" />
        <br />

        <label for="age">Votre Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
        <br />

        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="0" />

        <input type="button" name="buttonAjout" id="button1" value="Save" />
        <br />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="all" class="datagrid">
    <table class="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Id</td>
          <td>Nom</td>
          <td>Prenom</td>
          <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your ES6 syntax will fail in some popular browsers

Comment: @mplungjan You are right. Along with IE, as of now Safari still can not handle arrows. Yet, i just wanted to show the most recent and modern JS approach. One can always replace the arrows with their conventional counterparts. Other than the arrows the rest should be ES5 compliant.

Comment: Thanks u guys, u r awesome... :D